# How to stop Reality Composer Swift file from being auto generated for iOS 12 target?

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I am writing an app with RealityKit features. I want to have it supporting iOS 12 as well. That means iOS 12 or lower will be able to use non-RealityKit features while iOS 13 will be able to use all of them.

After setting all the `@available` and `if #available` , however, build fails. The reason is the auto-generated Swift file for the RCProject included in the Xcode project should be available for iOS 13 only.

How can I make the RCProject file to be compiled only if iOS 13 is available?

I have set all the `@available` and `if #available` for the RealityKit methods, to ensure RealityKit code will only be executed on iOS 13 devices.

- The auto-generated Swift file for Reality Composer Project, by Xcode itself

[image]

I expect the app to be successfully built for devices with iOS 12 or lower, but the build action fails as Experience.swift (RCProject auto-generated content built by Xcode itself and stored in Derived Data) cannot be compiled.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please include the code, not pictures of it.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The reason that no code is included is because the steps to reproduce this are:
1. New project and set it to deploy for iOS 12
2. Drag and drop an Experience.rcproj
3. Build and experience Swift Compiler Errors

Comment: It's embarrassing to say how long to figure out, how i fixed a somewhat related issue, how to import `CryptoKit` while still supporting ios 12. I finally got it working by adding -weak_framework "CryptoKit" under "Other linker flags" in my targets build settings. I'm sure this goes for `RealityKit`/`SwiftUI` as well.

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk - not embarrassing, you are just dealing with crappy documentation. Apple docs are created with disdain.

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk i tried your suggestion and it doesn't work as the file by RealityKit is auto generated and you can't edit it to attach `canImport`

Comment: @CrypticalV Did you solved it ?